# Accessing iLOM configuration from Solaris on SPARC

Tags: solaris, sun

Is there any way to get network configuration of iLOM in Solaris SPARC? I want to get the IP address of iLOM console at least.

It's pretty easy on x86 by `ipmitool lan print`, but for SPARC I can't find something that do the same. I found some mentions about `scadm` and `rscadm`, but those are not available for systems with iLOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ilomconfig in the [Sun/Oracle Hardware Management Pack](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/servermgmt/tech/hardware-management-pack/index.html) has a `list network` subcommand to print network configuration settings for the ILOM - [see the docs for details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20451_01/html/E25303/mpclt.gjuwa.html#scrolltoc).

Comment: Thanx for hint, but looks like it's crippled on SunOS10... don't have such options.

Answer (score 0):

ilomconfig is the solution on sparc systems

```
root@dos:~# ilomconfig network
Usage: ilomconfig <subcommand> <type> [options]
Enter 'ilomconfig <subcommand> --help' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:
    list          : Show ILOM settings, users, SNMP communities, and system summary
    create        : Create users and SNMP communities
    delete        : Delete users and SNMP communities
    modify        : Modify ILOM settings
    import        : Restore ILOM settings from an XML file
    export        : Backup ILOM settings to an XML file
    reset         : Reset ILOM to factory defaults
    enable        : Enable Host-to-ILOM interconnect
    disable       : Disable Host-to-ILOM interconnect

  General Options:
     -h, --help              : help
     -H, --remote-hostname   : hostname or IP address of the remote SP.
     -U  --remote-username   : username to login remote SP.
     -V, --version           : Show the version of the command.
     -q, --quiet             : Suppress informational message output and only return error codes.
     -y, --yes               : Execute command without prompting for confirmation.


Usage: ilomconfig <subcommand> <type> [options]
```